# RCA Android Viking Pro 10

Tags: factory-reset

Can't remember RCA viking pro 10 Google sign in or password. I did a factory reset and was stopped by the FPR request. I don't recall EVER "syncing" to a Google account. Is there any way I can get around this ?
   Thank You for any help.                John

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you're asking here: did you forget the password, or do you simply not want to use a Google account on the device, or only not enable syncing for specific (which?) items? Did you maybe mean you performed a [factory-reset](/tags/factory-reset/info) instead of a simple reboot, and now hit FRP (factory-reset protection)? Please [edit] your post and make it clear. While on it, also give it a clear title so folks with the appropriate knowledge know to chime in; with the current title only the few using that specific device might do so ;)

Comment: Thanks Izzy. I did indeed perform a factory-reset instead of a simple reboot, and now hit FRP (factory-reset protection.) I don't recall EVER "syncing" to a Google account. but that's what is being requested. Is there any other way of starting over or getting around the FRP?

Comment: What's important is not if you ever "synced" – but if you ever configured an Google account with that device. As for getting around the FRP: Have you followed the link to our wiki which I provided, and checked with the corresponding section? That's why I included the link in the first place ;)